# Metal compute shader with 1D data buffer in and out?

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, metal, compute-shader

I understand it is possible to pass a 1D array buffer to a metal shader, but is it possible to have it output to a 1D array buffer? I don't want it to write to a texture - I just need an array of processed values.

I can get values out with the shader with the following code, but they are one value at a time. Ideally I could get a whole array out (in the same order as the input 1D array buffer).

Any examples or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
var resultdata = [Float](repeating: 0, count: 3)
let outVectorBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: &resultdata, length: MemoryLayout<float3>.size, options: [])
commandEncoder!.setBuffer(outVectorBuffer, offset: 0, index: 6)

commandBuffer!.addCompletedHandler {commandBuffer in
    let data = NSData(bytes: outVectorBuffer!.contents(), length: MemoryLayout<float3>.size)
    var out: float3 = float3(0,0,0)
    data.getBytes(&out, length: MemoryLayout<float3>.size)
    print("data: \(out)")
}

//In the Shader:
kernel void compute1d(
    ...
    device float3 &outBuffer [[buffer(6)]],
    outBuffer = float3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You need to create the buffer large enough to hold however many `float3` elements as you want. You really need to use `.stride` and **not** `.size` when calculating the buffer size, though. In particular, `float3` has 16-byte alignment, so there's padding between elements in an array. So, you would use something like `MemoryLayout<float3>.stride * desiredNumberOfElements`.
- Then, in the shader, you need to change the declaration of `outBuffer` from a reference to a pointer. So, `device float3 *outBuffer [[buffer(6)]]`. Then you can index into it to access the elements (e.g. `outBuffer[2] = ...;`).

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can you show me how I would define `var out: float3`? C-style arrays are not allowed in Swift so I am not sure how that would look.